ValueError: Operands are not aligned. Do `left, right = left.align(right, axis=1, copy=False)` before operating
I do I get this error: "ValueError: Operands are not aligned. Do left, right = left.align(right, axis=1, copy=False) before operating.", I have no clue, if you know please help me
    # MACD Parameters
    macd_f = 12
    macd_s = 26
    macd_s_p = 9
    
    # Ensure 'Close' is a 1D array
    close_prices = data['Close'].values.flatten()  # Convert to numpy array
    
    # Calculate MACD and Signal Line using TA-Lib
    macd, macd_signal, _ = talib.MACD(close_prices, fastperiod=macd_f, slowperiod=macd_s, signalperiod=macd_s_p)
    
    # VWAP Calculation
    data['VWAP'] = (data['Volume'] * (data['High'] + data['Low'] + data['Close']) / 3).cumsum() / data['Volume'].cumsum()
    
    data['Buy_Signal'] = np.where((data['MACD'] > data['MACD_Signal']) & (data['Close'] > data['VWAP']), 1, 0)```





full error message!

The error means that you are making operations betweens objects that don't have the same index or columns. Check the dimensions. On what line do you have this error?  You don't show how data['MACD'] is built. Flatten will change to a dimension (N, ) not (N, 1). Try close_prices = data['Close'].

@rehaqds If I do that I get "TypeError: Argument 'real' has incorrect type (expected numpy.ndarray, got DataFrame)" calculating the MACD

So try close_prices = data['Close'].values as it will be a np.ndarray. What about my other points?

@rehaqds If I do that I get that the array has wrong dimentions, I think VWAP, MACD and MACD_Signal are all same dimensions and size
